# Mount LUKS Ext4 USB Pen Drive in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, luks

I want to mount an encrypted USB Pen Drive under Nautilus, but I get `Unable to open a folder for 16 GB Volume - No application is registered as handling this file`. It works if I use the terminal.[image: gnome-terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what was the problem: wrong permissions in `/media/<username>`.
If you have the same error message, then `umount` everything, go to `/media`, and delete your directory. Nautilus will recreate it with (hopefully) the right permissions.
WARNING: Be sure nothing is mounted int `/media/<username>`, because you might loose your data.
NOTE: If this problem comes up again, I'll create a bug report on launchpad.